# Excel 2010- nesting IF stmts -get "false" for result instead of number

Tags: excel-2010

Total hours in example = 33

The if statments I'm using:
`=IF(SUM(A5:A8)<39,(SUM(A5:A8)/8*$C$3),0)` works CORRECTLY for computing daily rental rate.
`=IF(SUM(A5:A8)>100,$E$3,0)` work CORRECTLY for computing monthly rental rate.
`=IF(SUM(A5:A8)<100,(IF(SUM(A5:A8)>39,SUM(A5:A8)/40*$N$3)),IF(SUM(A5:A8)<39,0))` does NOT work, it returns a "false" instead of a number, which in this case should be `0`.

How do I get the formula to return a number instead? Or is their a better way than using IF stmts? Thank you.

I have tried the MS website and other sources with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The central if staement `(IF(SUM(A5:A8)>39,SUM(A5:A8)/40*$N$3))` has no False clause, so returns the default value of False

It shou be `(IF(SUM(A5:A8)>39,SUM(A5:A8)/40*$N$3,some other expression))`